# Extremely disconnected space

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is called relative extremely disconnected if it has a base $B$(for open subsets) such that disjoint elements in B have disjoint closure, i.e, if $C, D$ in $B$ and $C\cap D=\emptyset$, then $clC\cap clD=\emptyset$.
Now, does $R$(real nubmer) with usual topology is a relative extremely disconnected space?

Comment: Ok. Does exist Hausdorff space $X$ which is not relative extremely disconnected space?

Comment: Avoid modern sloppiness.  Keep the original name "extremally disconnected".  Same for "basically disconnected".

Answer (score 12):

Actually real open intervals with rational left end-point and irrational right end-point are a base with that property.